# New remote head when pushing new branch

Tags: mercurial, push, branching-and-merging

I've created a `named` branch in mercurial, committed some changes, and now I want to push that back to the central repo. I've done a fetch, verified I have no changes to merge, but when I try to do the push, I'm getting the message `push creates new remote head` but I don't understand why. I'm the only dev on *this* branch and it is still local to my repository.

```
>hg fetch (pull/update/merge)
>hg status (shows nothing)
>hg push --new-branch mybranch
 searching for changes
 new remote heads on branch 'default'
 new remote head c3064f3cf1b7
 abort: push creates new remote head c3064f3cf1b7!
 (did you forget to merge? use push -f to force)
```

Any ideas?

**Edit**: sorry for any confusion, this *is* a named branch created by `hg branch mybranch`

**Update**: using `hg heads` yields multiple heads all on different branches. I have one for my branch, and one under default:

```
changeset:   515:97b9a7802751
branch:      mybranch
user:        me <me@mymail.com>
date:        Mon Feb 27 13:21:54 2012 -0800
files:       CryptoRandom.cs
description:
fixing error message for size of max


changeset:   504:c3064f3cf1b7
user:        me <me@mymail.com>
date:        Thu Feb 09 11:41:32 2012 -0800
files:       CipherKey.cs
description:
removing ambiguous characters - CAC-47
```

using `hg log -r c3064f3cf1b7` yields the following (this is the head on default):

```
changeset:   504:c3064f3cf1b7
user:        me <me@mymail.com>
date:        Thu Feb 09 11:41:32 2012 -0800
files:       CipherKey.cs
description:
removing ambiguous characters - CAC-47
```

Comment: `hg heads` will show you all heads. That ought to tell you where `c3064f3cf1b7` stands with other heads, too.

Comment: Folow-up to @JoelBFant: `hg log -r c3064f3cf1b7`. It seems you have not new named branch, but anonymous branch in default

Comment: added more info on the branch. I'm pretty sure it's a named branch...

Comment: And you've pulled everything for the `default` branch from the other repo that you wanted to push to?

Comment: I'm not working on `default` and not ready to merge back yet. Do I really need to switch to `default` and pull?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just magically resolved this, yet still not clear why. It does seem to be a problem with `default` even though I'm not working on that branch. I could call `>hg branch` and get the expected branch name.

I had a change in my local `default` branch that was not pushed, and did not want. I backed out of that change and then committed. I then did a `fetch` on the default branch and merged that to my feature branch. Then back on `default` I  merged with the changeset on default that I backed out of I believe. At some point during that process I got yet another head, which probably caused the multiple merges.

It all seems to boil down to existing heads on default, but I still do not know why (or why we would want to) that affects a separate named branch.

This all seem overly complicated for what I expect to happen (and what everyone can simply draw out in ascii diagrams)

**Edit**

It looks like the problem stemmed during the initial branch perhaps. It looks like I branched twice and `[j]` is an anonymous branch on default.

to sort of visualize what seems to be going on `[j]` is my changeset I backed out of and `[k]` is my first commit on mybranch:

```
[a] -- [b] -- [c] -- [d] -- [e]  (default)
         \             \    /
          [j]-----------\---     (not sure where this branch came from)
            \            \
            [k] -- [l] -- [m]    (mybranch. Still separate from default)
```

Answer (score 14):

The confusing is that the `--new-branch` flag has no effect when pushing feature branches (also known as *anynomous* branches). An anonymous branch looks like this:

```
... [a] --- [b] --- [c] <- the servers head on default
               \
                [x] --- [y] <- my feature branch on default
```

All changesets are on `default` so you now have **two heads** on `default`. When you push, you will create two heads on the server — but Mercurial aborts before that with the warning you see. It aborts since having multiple heads on a server is confusing: when you `hg clone` your working copy will be updated to one of them, almost at random.

The `--new-branch` flag is only for [*named* branches](http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/en/tasks/#pushing-a-branch). Mercurial will normally abort if you push a new named branch to a remote repository. Adding the `--new-branch` flag is how you tell it to go ahead.

Unfortunately, we don't have a dedicated `--create-new-feature-branch` flag. We only have the `--force` flag which tells Mercurial to go ahead and create the two heads in the remote repository. The downside of `--force` is that it overrules all safety checks: you can push three or more new heads with that flag and you can even push into an unrelated repository.
So you should use `hg outgoing` to double check what you're going to push.

I wrote above that multiple heads on the server is confusing since a new clone will be updated to a random head. To avoid the confusion you can give the feature branches names by *bookmarking* them. You will still be updated to a random head, but `hg bookmarks` will show you the available feature branches and you can then update to the right one. So if you're using such a workflow, then go ahead with `hg push -f`.

Comment: I type `hg branch` and I get my branch name: `php7` as opposed to `default`. But I still couldn't push with `--new-branch`. Does that mean that I wasn't in a named branch? How is this possible? I found the only way to push was `hg push -f` but that didn't feel right for my new branch named `php7`